# Unique Number of Requests for Each Customer ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to achieve something like this screenshot: the unique number of requests for each customer ID using "formula"
NOTE: There are duplicate customer IDs and request IDs
[image: I want to achieve something like this]

Comment: Take a look at `COUNTIF`

Comment: vain attempt ...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `COUNTIFS(), this counts for each ID given in column A. The formula can be dragged down and the data range B3:C8 can be expanded as necessary

If you also want the total sold as well, then SUMIFS() is what you need:

Edit to put in cell G2 etc as requested...
[image]

Comment: The formula should be in G2 for the first customer, G3 for the second, and so forth. I appreciate a working example.

Comment: Move the formulas to where you want them.

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a mistake in making my point the right way. Now, I edited my question and uploaded another shot. This is what I mean.

Comment: countifs() will still do this : I will let you expand it appropriately as I have given you a sufficient example

Answer (score 0):

Formula in G2

```
={SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(IF($A$2:$A$10=F2,$B$2:$B$10,""))>0,MATCH(IF($A$2:$A$10=F2,$B$2:$B$10,""),IF($A$2:$A$10=F2,$B$2:$B$10,""),0),""), IF(LEN(IF($A$2:$A$10=F2,$B$2:$B$10,""))>0,MATCH(IF($A$2:$A$10=F2,$B$2:$B$10,""),IF($A$2:$A$10=F2,$B$2:$B$10,""),0),""))>0,1))}
```

[image]

The formula here must be entered as array formula. Select cell that contains a formula, press F2, and then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Comment: Yeah.. It is... refer https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273 for explaination. Accept the answer if the problem is resolved.